# Split an array in many parts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In a Rails 3.2 application, I have an array like that :

```
arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
```

And I want to split it in 3 parts like this :

```
[["a", "b"], ["c", "d"], ["e"]]
```

I want to a have function to have the first part of this array.

I always want to have 3 parts. So, if I have :

```
["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h"]
```

I want to have :

```
[["a", "b", "c"], ["d", "e", "f"], ["g", "h"]]
```

Do you have a simple solution?

Comment: You could use [`Enumerable#each_slice`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice), e.g., `arr.each_slice(2).to_a`.

Comment: You solution does not works for me. I always want to have 3 parts. I updated my question.

Comment: Not sure if there is a simpler solution, but you could always write your own method for doing this, e.g., https://gist.github.com/O-I/df37c60842ab232c47a0

Answer (score 1):

```
["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"].in_groups_of(2, false)
# => [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"], ["e"]]
```

If you always want 3 parts, this should do it

```
parts_count = 3
group_count = arr.length.fdiv(parts_count).ceil
arr.in_groups_of(group_count, false)
# => [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"], ["e"]]
```

More info [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html#method-i-in_groups_of).

Comment: I updated my question. I want to always have the array splitted in 3 parts.